# Affine Texture Mapping in d3d11/hlsl

Tags: directx, hlsl

I am wondering if you happen to know how to change the default perspective correct texturing to affine texturing in HLSL or d3d11. I have to do specifically this for an assignment I am working on and any help would be great.
THANKS!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Yes, any help would be great, but first you should try doing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There are so called [interpolation modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509668(v=vs.85).aspx#Remarks) that do exactly this. You want `noperspective`. The declaration would look as follows:

```
noperspective float2 texCoords;
```